# Extension method on collection from entity in entity framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to add an extension method to a collection of entities that are children to a parent entity, here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

Parent = Parent entity.

Child = Child entity.

Parent.Children.Add('Dave');

My extension method would be the Add method above, now the spec for this method would be:

```
public static void Add(this ICollection<Child> children, string nameOfChild) {}
```

Within my extension method I would create a new child instance and set the name and add it to the collection.  This I can do.  However, in this function I want to access the parent instance, but i've only got a handle to the instance of the children collection.

So my question is; is it possible to access the parent instance from just having the children collection?  And if so, how please?

Comment: Can you give a higher level explanation of what you're trying to do? Why do you need an extension method instead of just using the common pattern `Parent.Children.Add(new Child('Dave'));`? Are you trying to accomplish something special when the child is added?

Comment: The child will have certain properties set to certain values based on properties that are in the parent, and to keep these "business rules" in one tidy place, I'd like to put them in this extension method.

Comment: I'd try writing those properties on the child class to have a dummy setter and a getter that accesses properties of the Parent through its navigation property. That way when EF accesses those properties at SaveChanges time it should get the correct values without you having to explicity set them.

Comment: If I were to add the child to the collection within this extension method, I don't think the navigational properties get set up (I may be wrong)?  Is there a way of refreshing/forcing the child to get it's navigational properties set up without calling SaveChanges?